# Get detailed number of Rows affected by insert statement

Tags: sql, database-partitioning, rows-affected

My table is setup with one of the columns named 'Month".
I run a sql insert statement on the table, and get the number of rows affected.

Is there a way to get the number of rows affected for each value of "Month"?

If my table is partition on the "Month" column, can that help?

My sql a standard one like follows:

INSERT INTO 'TargetTable'
(Column1, Column2, Months, Column4,....)
SELECT column_names
FROM SourceTable;

I'm using SqlCommand from .Net's SqlClient to pass the sql into SQL server.

Comment: Please include your sql.

Answer (score 1):

A single `insert` statement returns a single rows affected count. You perform a separate insert for each value of 'month', so 12 insert statements instead of 1. That will have some performanc impact.

Alternatively, you could load the rows to be inserted into a temp table and do the insert and then report on things, something along these lines:

```
create table #work
( month                     int not null ,
  primary_key_of_real_table int not null ,
)
insert #work
select t.month , t.primary_key_column
from source_table t
where -- your filter criteria here

insert target_table
( ... column list ... )
select ... column list ...
from #work t
join source_table x on x.primary_key_column =t.primary_key_of_real_table

select m.month , cnt = sum(case when t.month is null then 1 else 0 end)
from ( select month = 1 union all
       select month = 2 union all
       ...
       select month = 12
     ) m
left join #work t on t.month = m.month
group by t.month
order by t.month
```

Comment: Thanks you.  I grouped my insert statements for performance reasons, so can not pursue this option due to the same concerns.